# How can I disable a variadic arguments constructor of a container whenever the underlying storage type would make copies of the elements?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T, class Tuple>
class vector
{
public:
    template<typename... Elements, typename = decltype(Tuple{ static_cast<T>(std::declval<Elements>())... })>
    vector(Elements&&... elements)
        : m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }
    { }

private:
    Tuple m_elements;
};

int main()
{
    // (1) Will invoke std::vector<foo>::vector(std::initializer_list<foo>)
    // -> a foo copy will be made:
    vector<foo, std::vector<foo>> x = { foo{"vector-foo"} };
    // (2) Will use aggregate initialization -> no copies of foo will be made:
    vector<foo, std::array<foo, 1>> y = { foo{"array-foo"} };

    return 0;
}
```

How can I disable the constructor whenever a copy of `T` would be made? I've made a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/050706fd580be8e4) which contains the definition of `foo`.

Comment: Do you want to know if `Tuple` is an aggregate ?

Comment: @Jarod42 No. `std::array<T, N>` is an aggregate and yes, (2) is using aggregate initialization such that all rvalues inside the braces are moveable. However, it would be perfectly fine, if `Tuple` is *any* type which provides a ctor of the form `Tuple(Elements&&... elements)` which moves the `elements` whenever possible. In any other case (i.e. if I can't be sure that the `Tuple` ctor would move the `elements` whenever possible), I don't want to provide my ctor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why am I doing that? It's cause one would expect that an ctor of my form moves the `elements` whenever possible and I want to force the user of `vector` to use another possibility (e.g. via the omitted `operator[]`) to initialize the elements otherwise.